# Big O notation, Complexity

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, pseudocode

So we're just beginning Big O notation, and we have a question asking this:

What is the worst time complexity for the following loop, if `someWork` has complexity of `O(i)`, noting that this means that `i` is the loop counter, so the steps of someWork increases every time the counter does:

```
while(i < n)
    someWork(...)
    i <-- i + 2
```

This is obviously written in pseudocode, and I've gotten the easier questions, so I don't believe I have a problem understanding the question, it's this specific one that I'm stuck on. Can I get some help, please?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: let's say n is a big positive integer and i is 0. so, the loop may go on for n/2 times, since i is increased by 2 everytime.

Comment: Ok, for example, the first question was "What is the worst case time complexity of this loop if 'someWork' is an 'O(1)' algorithm?


This is the last question in a series of questions that increased in difficulty
I got the answer to be 'O(n/2)'

Comment: If the answer is O( n/2 ), it means that `someWork()` doesn't have complexity O( i ) but O( 1 ). The thing is : O( n/2 ) pretty much means O( n ).

Comment: Thanks for that, I had another class today and realized that mistake.
Great reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `someWork()` is dependent on `i`, and `i` is, on average, roughly `n/2` over *all* the outer loop iterations, the time complexity is therefore `O(n2)`.

That's because the outer loop depends on `n` and `someWork()` (an "inner loop" of some description) also depends on `n`.

The reasoning behind `someWork()` being `O(n)` is as follows.

Let's say `n` is 8. That means `i` takes the values `{0, 2, 4, 6}`, an average of `12 / 4 == 3`.

Now let's say `n` is 16. That means `i` takes the values `{0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14}`, an average of `56 / 8 == 7`.

Now let's say `n` is 32. That means `i` takes the values `{0, 2, 4, ..., 28, 30}`, an average of `240 / 16 == 15`.

If you continue, you will find that the number of operations performed by `someWork()` is always `n / 2 - 1` hence `O(n)`.

That, in combination with the loop itself being `O(n)`, gives you the `O(n2)` complexity.

Comment: I like this, but we aren't looking for the average, we're looking for the worst case. Is this the same in this instance?
Sorry... first time really working with O notation.

Comment: @Auxilio, don't make the mistake of thinking my use of the word "average" relates to the complexity. I'm using the average just to show that the `someWork()` function depends on `n`. It's similar to `1+2+3+4+5 = 3*5` (middle number by count), `1+2+3 = 2*3`, 1+2+...+n = (n+1)/2 * n`.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends upon the complexity of `someWork()`. If `someWork()` has a loop (or nested loops) inside, the complexity will automatically go from O(n) to O(n^2) or more. If someWork has no loops, this code has O(n) complexity. BTW, I have a hard time trying to understand that last line. Is it part of the loop? Is it assigning anything to i (a typo I mean)?

Comment: It won't necessarily go from O(n) to O(n^2) if there is a nested for loop. What if the nested for loop iterates over an empty list? His pseudocode not sufficient

Comment: @TheInternet: Complexities do not care for best case scenarios. It is normally the average and worst time that matters. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o?rq=1.

Comment: The pseudocode itself may not be sufficient but the text clearly states that someWork is O(i) which is effectively O(n) in this scenario. I'd vote this up except dotNET seems to have missed the fact the complexity  of someWork has actually been specified.

Comment: With the specified complexity of someWork, what would the resulting O notation be?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the question a bit, suppose the last line is replaced with
    i <--- i + 1
so that you aren't skipping values of `i`. Now, how much work is done? The total is,

O(1) + O(2) + O(3) + O(4) + ... + O(n-1) + O(n) = O(1 + 2 + ... + n) = O(n(n+1)/2) = O(n^2).

Now, in your problem, we are leaving out all the even values of i, which is the same as deleting half of the terms. It shouldn't be too hard to see that this should add up to something that is roughly 1/2 as many operations, so we get O(n^2/2) = O(n^2).